# Managed C++ with .NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, c++, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

We have a library written in C++. To make it more compatible with our more modern .NET projects, we wrapped this C++ library in another .NET project. It works fine when referencing it from full .NET Framework projects (4.5, 4.6, etc.).

I am creating a new application using .NET Core 2.1 and I am trying to reference this "wrapped-in-.NET C++ library". On my first attempt, it failed saying the assembly couldn't be loaded. I fixed this problem by installing .NET Core SDK x86 and forcing my application to use **x86**, not **Any CPU**.

I get no build errors, but when I try to instantiate a class within this library, I get the following exception:

```
<CrtImplementationDetails>.ModuleLoadException: The C++ module failed to load.
 ---> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: A library name must be specified in a DllImport attribute applied to non-IJW methods.
   at _getFiberPtrId()
   at <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport._Initialize(LanguageSupport* )
   at <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.Initialize(LanguageSupport* )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at <CrtImplementationDetails>.ThrowModuleLoadException(String errorMessage, Exception innerException)
   at <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.Initialize(LanguageSupport* )
   at .cctor()
```

Does .NET Core 2.1 support this scenario at all?

Comment: What is the .NET version of the wrapper project?

Comment: Hi @ahelwer, it's .NET 4.0

Comment: By the way, we also tried using .NET 4.6 but it returned the same error.

Comment: To be clear - is this wrapper project a .NET project calling the native library with PInvoke, or a C++/CLI project (aka "managed C++")?

Comment: C++/CLI (aka "managed C++").

Comment: Right, as others answered C++/CLI is not supported by .NET Core, although PInvoke works fine as you discovered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As others pointed out, .NET Core [does not currently support C++/CLI](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/659) (aka "managed C++"). If you want to call into native assemblies in .NET Core, you must use [PInvoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop) (as you discovered).

You can also compile your .NET Core project in AnyCPU, as long as you keep around both 32- & 64-bit versions your native library and add special branching logic around your PInvoke calls:

```
using System;

public static class NativeMethods
{
    public static Boolean ValidateAdminUser(String username, String password)
    {
        if (Environment.Is64BitProcess)
        {
            return NativeMethods64.ValidateAdminUser(username, password);
        }
        else
        {
            return NativeMethods32.ValidateAdminUser(username, password);
        }
    }

    private static class NativeMethods64
    {
        [DllImport("MyLibrary.amd64.dll", EntryPoint = "ValidateAdminUser", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern Boolean ValidateAdminUser(String username, String password);
    }

    private static class NativeMethods32
    {
        [DllImport("MyLibrary.x86.dll", EntryPoint = "ValidateAdminUser", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern Boolean ValidateAdminUser(String username, String password);
    }
}
```

Where you have your MyLibrary.amd64.dll and MyLibrary.x86.dll assemblies in the same directory. It would be nice if you could put relative paths into DllImport and have x86/amd64 subdirectories, but I haven't figured out how to do that.

Answer (score 6):

No it does not. .NET core is cross platform but C++/CLI is not, the Microsoft C++ compiler requires Windows.

Comment: For more information, see [Will CoreCLR support C++/CLI crossplat?](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/659)

Answer (score 2):

**PInvoke** seems to be the only way to go.

Put the library DLL in the solution folder (the actual C++ DLL, not a .NET wrapper).

**NOTE:** Don't reference the DLL in the solution, just place the DLL in the same folder.

Then use **DLL Import** to access the methods:

```
static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("MyLibrary.dll", EntryPoint = "ValidateAdminUser", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern Boolean ValidateAdminUser(String username, String password);
}
```

**NOTE 2:** It still requires the .NET Core project to run in x86 architecture.